# Generate the schema.rb from Rails Models (without Database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails project that has an outdated `schema.rb` file. I also have an empty database. How do I generate the `schema.rb` from the Rails Models?

Comment: Do you have migration code in `db/migrate` folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try;

`rake db:schema:load`

Comment: Try using reset before hand just in case.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be generating a schema from your models, but rather your database or migration files. If your migrations are up to date and reflect the state of your database, you can run:

```
bundle exec rake db:schema:dump
```

It should generate the `schema.rb` file from your database.

This is what Rails runs after the **db:migrate** task has executed:

```
Rake::Task["db:schema:dump"].invoke if ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format == :ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveRecord models don't store any information about the database schema. The schema is stored in the `schema.rb` file.

The file is generated from the database, at the end of every migration. Therefore, if you have an up-to-date database, simply run:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

to sync the schema. If you have an empty database, then there is no way to update the schema (actually, at that point I wonder what your Rails models are using).

The only thing you can do is:

1. load the current schema and migrate from that
2. reuse the migrations, assuming they are up to date